# Динамический фильтр в WHERE MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть ли способ, кроме динамического запроса, сделать внутри `WHERE` своего рода `IF` `ELSE`? В процедуру попадает 3 аргумента : дата с, дата по и код. Я хочу что бы, если код равен пусто или `null` использовать фильтр по дате, иначе по коду. Я думал над вариантом `IF ELSE` внутри процедуры перед запросами, то есть сделать два запроса, один по коду, один по дате и согласно значения аргумента "код" отправлять в `IF` или в `ELSE`, но этот вариант мне кажется костылем. Прошу подсказать.

Comment: как вариант можно так `where table.code = isnull(@code,table.code)`

Comment: Советую посмотреть статью [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да хоть бы и совсем тупо так:

```
WHERE (@code IS NOT NULL AND table.code = @code) 
   OR (@code IS NULL AND table.date BETWEEN @start AND @end)
```

Если в @code может передаваться некое "пусто" (он что, строковый?), то вместо `@code IS [NOT] NULL` поставьте что-нибудь вроде `COALESCE(@CODE, '') [= | !=] ''`. А если он всё же числовой, и "пусто" - это ноль, то соответственно `COALESCE(@CODE, 0) [= | !=] 0`.

Comment: Код тип varchar